# How to Sort the System Drives in QTreeView using QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qfilesystemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a **QTreeview** where I am displaying all system drives using **QFileSystemModel**. I am looking for much better approach where a **QTreeview** can display Local Drives in one section, Removable Drive in another and so on. Basically sort the drives.

Here is the code:

```
pSystemPrimaryModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);    
pSystemPrimaryModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
pSystemPrimaryModel->setFilter( QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot );

// Sets the model for the view to present.
ui->PrimTreeView->setModel(pSystemPrimaryModel);

// Just Display NAME and hide other Columns
for(int nCount = 1; nCount < pSystemPrimaryModel->columnCount(); nCount++)
ui->PrimTreeView->hideColumn(nCount);
```

This basically gives me all the drives as follows:

```
Name:
+ C:
+ New Volume(D:)
+ New Volume(E:)
+ SD_Card(F:)
+ Transcend Drive(G:)
```

Using **hideColumn()** I have hidden all the header(Except Name) which gets displayed when QTreeView is used i.e. **Name, Type, Size** etc.

***My Requirement:***

1. What I basically want to achieve is this:

   - Local Folder

     - C:
     - New Volume(D:)
     - New Volume(E:)
   - Removable Drives

     - SD_Card(F:)
     - Transcend Drive(G:)

Basically separate the local drives and external ones. I have come across **QSortFilterProxyModel** which looks like it sorts the drive order. But I have no clue how to use that.

1. I want to remove the header in QTreeView. Since **Name** is visible in my output, I want to hide it. 
   It would be helpful if you could guide me :)